# How to access a json object in javascript files from a model passed to the view

Tags: javascript, json, razor, model-view-controller

I have a JSON object in my database that contains html inside it. I pass the object as part of a model to my view. I need to access the object and read it in the javascript files for the page. However when i try and assign the object to a global variable in my html file i cannot access it in my javascript file.

I tried reading the object as a string it returns decoded html (
	"page-1":) which i cant do anything with. If i call @Html.Raw(@Model.CourseContent.ExpectedResult) it created the JSON object as expected. However in my javascript file it is listed as undefined. I have no idea how to solve this.

```
@model DataTransferObjects.Models.UserCourseAndContent
<script>
    var totalPages = '@Model.CourseContent.TotalPages';
    var expectedResults = @HTML.Raw(@Model.CourseContent.ExpectedResult)

</script>
```

The json object that comes out when i use the above code looks like

```
var expectedResults = {
    "page-1": "<head></head><body></body>",
    "page-3": "<head></head><body><h1>My Cool News Article</h1><p>Welcome 
                    to my news article, you’ll find some cool news here.</p> 
    <Our most recent 
    news</<p>Below you’ll find my most recent news!</p></body>"
    };
```

I expected it to be an actual json string but instead ive got an object (?) i am confused as to how to decode the html out of it then turn the resulting json obejct into a json string to be read in the javascript file.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var expectedResults = {
    "page-1": "<head></head><body></body>",
    "page-3": "<head></head><body><h1>My Cool News Article</h1><p>Welcome 
                    to my news article, you’ll find some cool news here.</p> 
    <Our most recent 
    news</<p>Below you’ll find my most recent news!</p></body>"
    };

// Parse JSON
const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(expectedResults));

// Access to properties
const page-1 = parsedJSON['page-1'];
const page-3 = parsedJSON['page-3'];
```